# CSS works differently on certain pages, difference disappears when using development tools

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a weird one: on my site http://tustincommercial.com some pages are aligned slightly differently from others, giving a jumping effect.

Compare http://tustincommercial.com vs http://tustincommercial.com/who-we-are to see the effect.

The markup is identical, apart from the content in the middle. The same CSS is being applied.

Now, the real killer is that **this difference disappears when developer tools are open.** All browsers (IE8, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera) show the difference when developer tools are not open. None of them show the difference when their developer tools are open.

Any ideas on the best way to find and fix the source of the difference?

Comment: They both look identical to me in FF4 & IE8 & Chrome 11, whats supposed to jump around?

Comment: @Alex K.: First, thanks for looking. In all browsers mentioned, everything (header, footer bar content, the blue frame in the body) are some 9px to the left on the second page (who-we-are). If you flip between tabs, you should see the effect.

Comment: @Mu is too short: I think it might well be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the scrollbar appearing when your content goes past the bottom of the window.  When the developer tools are open **all** pages need to scroll, so the jump disappears.

There are a few ways to fix this, but I currently can't tell you what would be best for your site.  You could make it fixed width, you could try using `max-width`, or you could force the scroll bar to always be present:

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ah, good spot. How would max-width help? (Sorry if the answer is obvious)/

Comment: To be super picky, it's probably more appropriate to put that css on the body tag, instead of html (because html doesn't generate a box).

Comment: @marcin, putting the code in body is a fair point.  `max-width` may help you keep your pages generally the same width (thus the same overflow) so you can layout your content to always have scrollbars. `overflow-y:scroll` is a better solution than that in this case I believe